# Function resolution from vtable in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions, vtable

I have a confusion regarding vtable after reading more about name mangling.
for ex:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
    }
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    void hello()
    {
        ....
    }

    void print()
    {
    }
};

A obj;
obj.hello();

Base* test = new A();
test->print();
```

As per my understanding after the name manging `obj.hello()` call will be converted to something like `_ZASDhellov(&obj)` now

1. how this virtual functions will be invoked from vtable?
2. my wild guess `test->__vtable[_ZASDprintv](&test(dynamic cast to derived???))` is correct?
3. How the function names are resolved from vtable?

Comment: `A::hello()` is not a virtual function.

Comment: There are no virtual functions and thus no vtable in the code you show.

Comment: i know. if it is a virtual function how it will be evaluated?

Comment: @GilsonPJ Depends. Please post a [mcve] that exhibits the virtual call you want to know about.

Comment: The C++ language does not deal with vtables, and implementations don't have to use them to implement virtual functions. Details will differ from implementation to implementation.

Comment: Did you mean `A::hello` and `Base::print` to be the same name?  This would make your example a *lot* easier to understand!

Comment: @MartinBonner thanks and updated the code :)

Comment: I am getting lot of down vote for this, but i couldn't able to understand what is the wrong with this question? Yes I agree that code sample I provided making lot of confusion but I believe my question is clear. I don't care about the down votes. but I am eager to understand how it is resolved from vtable. I goggled it many times and I couldn't able to find out how it is resolving

Comment: You may believe your question is clear.  I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, vtables are not in any way part of the C++ language, but rather an implementation detail used by particular compilers. Below I describe one way it is commonly used as such.

Second, your function `hello` is not virtual. To make it virtual, you would simply pre-pend `virtual` to the declaration.

Assuming it is now virtual: Your guess is quite close. In fact, the `vtable` (to which a pointer is stored with every instance of a virtual class) is an array of function pointers. The way that a particular function is looked up in it is by its ordinal. The first declared virtual function in `A` is the first entry in its `vtable`, the second one is the second entry and so on. If `A` had a base class, the index of `A`'s first (non-override) virtual function in the table would be `n+1`, where `n` is the index of the last virtual function of its base class. If `A` has more than one base class, their entries precede `A`'s entries in order of their declaration as base classes of `A`.

If `A` uses virtual inheritance, the picture is a bit more complicated than that, I won't elaborate unless you're specifically interested.

**UPDATE:** I'll add a very brief description for the virtual inheritance case as requested. If `A` had `Base` as a virtual base class, `A`'s `vtable` would store at the very beginning (before the function addresses) the byte offset of where `Base`'s data starts within the `A` object. This is necessary because, unlike in normal inheritance, a base class does not have its data precede the derived class's data - instead it follows it. So in effect, any function call to a virtual function defined in `Base` has to have its `this` pointer offset by that amount. Additionally,  `Base` would have to have its own `vtable` pointer, right at the beginning of its data where it expects to find it. Thus the full `A` object would contain two `vtable` pointers instead of one. The actual `vtable` pointed to by this second pointer would be the same one as the first `vtable` pointer, except advanced to skip the offset entry described above (so that any `Base` code using the `vtable` would find the first virtual function at the beginning where it is expected). Apart from these differences, the `vtable` itself is the same as before.

Comment: I would phrase as "If `A` had a base class, the index of `A`'s first "... - it took me a couple of seconds to realize the antecedent of "it" was `A`, not "the base class".  +1 for mentioning virtual inheritance (which gets close to the point where I say "because magic").

Comment: THANK YOU @Smeeheey Now the picture is clear. It will be helpful if you can explain if A uses virtual inheritance.

Comment: I added a brief explanation